# Salt Lake City to Denver winter

Tags: safety, winter, denver, salt-lake-city

We are moving this week from SLC to Denver driving a budget truck and car.  Looking for routes with the least chance of snow and with the shortest possible of those routes.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Taking I-80 across Wyoming, then dropping down along I-25 is the fastest and the least amount of mountain driving.  But it does have potential for issues with blowing snow.

Dropping down the through Price then across I-70 is your other main option.  less chance for blowing snow, but more climbing and descending on potentially snowy roads.

Fortunately Interstates tend to be first priority for plowing.  So unless it is snowing heavily the day you make the drive, they should be relatively clear (though packed snow and icy patches are always something to watch for).

Just re-read and noticed the this week mention ... the ten day forecast all call for decent weather, so either route could be fine with maybe a slight chance for icy patches at higher altitudes on the I-70 route.

Comment: I noticed I-80 had some wind warnings.  Do you think a 16-ft Budget truck would have any problems with this wind broadside?

Comment: It really would depend on how strong the winds are.  Side winds would make the truck feel more squirrelly as you drive down the road, but wouldn't be a safety or big control issue unless the road was totally iced over or if the winds were real strong say 40 mph or higher.